# Second view controller not showing

Tags: ios, segue

I have two view controllers, the main linked to a navigation controller. I created a segue by linking the main controller to the second on the storybaord. I've called the Identifier "Associate" and made it a push segue.
I create table view cells with a button attached to the accessory view programatically (this is deliberate). The button calls performSegueWithIdentifier, but it doesn't show the second view controller. Aside my iffy technical language (only been IOS for a week, sorry) any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
//...
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonizeButtonTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.accessoryView = myButton;

return cell;
}

-(void)buttonizeButtonTap:(id)sender{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Associate" sender:sender];
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the buttonizeButtonTap: method is called? What are you seeing? Does the first controller go away, but you just have a blank view, or does nothing happen when you touch the button?

Comment: Don't know if this is actually in your code but you say `@selctor`, instead of `@selector`. And try changing `sender:` to self.

Comment: sorry, typed in rather copied (different computers). The method is being called. Absolutely nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: Do you have a class for the "Associate" ViewController? Are the ``init`` or ``viewDidLoad`` methods of that class being called?

Comment: I have a class associated with the second controller, but the viewDidLoad is not called. By init, can this also mean initWithNibName()? (that's not called either).

Comment: Check in Storyboard if you have assigned the class to the view controller. Sometimes you forget and your code never gets called.

Comment: double checked. Both view controllers are linked to their respective classes. Just to add, performSegueWithIdentifier is called (not that I do anything with it at the moment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, realised what I did wrong. I had put an empty performSegueWithIdentifier method override. The danger of running before I can walk. Thanks for all your help.